# Bluring a content on a website during screenshots/recordings

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, spring-boot

I've been coding a messenger, and a few days ago I came across netflix's protection against screnshots and screen recordings, and I wonder, how did they do it? I tried searching it online, read a bunch of forums, but found nothing, and everyone says that this is impossible, though netflix has it, and it works in most cases. I've got spring boot/security backend, and angularjs frontend for my website. Does anyone know how to implement this mechanic into a website?

Comment: What specifically are you talking about? What does Netflix "have"? Most times you watch a video and there's something blurred out that's during video production. To blur a screen you have to blur all the important parts, not just web content.

Answer (score 0):

Try css blur. There are also many answers on stack overflow for how to do this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/blur

```
style="filter: blur(4px);"
```

Comment: Well, the thing is, that it should not be blurred the whole time, but only when taking a picture or recording a screen.

Comment: You would have to set the blurr css attribute to the element you want to blur somewhere in your function to record/take a picture.